# Fabricjs - setBackgroundImage to Empty URL causes null reference error in _setWidthHeight

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I found an article that explained how to clear the background of a fabric canvas...

canvas.setBackgroundImage('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

I have built an online design tool utilizing Fabricjs 1.4.4 and have incorporated quite a bit of functionality but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.  I can set the canvas to an actual image url and it displays correctly, but when I used the suggested code to REMOVE the background image (shown above) I get a javascript error in Fabric.js:

Unhandled exception at line 16045, column 7 in .../fabric.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'width' of undefined or null reference.

The line referenced is from the _setWidthHeight method

Am I doing something wrong?  This seems like it should be fairly straight forward but I cannot remove the background image...whether one exists or not.

K-Dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If setting the background image to an empty string doesn't work try and set it to 0.

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(0, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

This works for us.
regards,
Benick